# Excel Web Add-In using Querytables

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

Does anyone know how to use the [Querytable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable) object in an Excel Web Add-In?

I developed an Excel VSTO Add-In previously and would now like to use the same functionality instead of with VB in JS.

So lets say I just want to insert a querytable like I would with the following code in VB in JS:

```
QT = new_Ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=xConnection, Destination:=new_Ws.Range("A1"))
With QT
    .WebSelectionType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWebSelectionType.xlAllTables
    .Refresh(False)
End With
```

How would I do that (I suppose in the Home.js file) in JavaScript?

The big question is: does the Web Add-In support the [Querytables.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add) function?

I could not try it, because I cannot find any documentation by Microsoft on JavaScript code, only VS (see the two links that I posted above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OfficeJS doesn't provide any direct analog. You may find [Excel JavaScript API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview) for the reference. See [Work with PivotTables using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-pivottables) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.